# Why doesn't this XMLHttprequest return any data to "text_string"?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, server, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to write a program that reads a text file I have hosted on my site and writes its contents on a canvas.

My code fails after I make a send request (test3 doesn't get written to the canvas).

I have waited several minutes for the request to complete, but it fails.

I made the request Synchronous, but it shouldn't take so long, right?

```
const cvs = document.getElementById("holdingscanvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

const fileURL = "/url_to_txt_file";

ctx.fillText("test1", 10, 40, 500);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

ctx.fillText("test2", 10, 80, 500);

request.open("GET", fileURL, false);
request.send(null);

ctx.fillText("test3", 10, 120, 500);

if (request.responseText == null)
{
    ctx.fillText("Crash?", 10, 160, 500);
}

var text_string = request.responseText;

ctx.fillText(text_string, 10, 160, 500);
```

I'm 100% confident "fileURL" is correct. I've heard about **node.js**, but my site runs on WordPress, and I don't think I have access to those file reading capabilities.

Comment: Try adding a "." in front of the "/" in your file URL, not sure it will help but it may

Comment: `My code fails` - what is shown in your browsers **developer** console? (Besides the warning about deprecated synchronous XMLHttpRequest) - also is "fileURL" a full URL, or just a path? i.e. is this a cross origin or same origin request?

Comment: by adding a '.' the code outputted some html, not only the bit of text I needed. @Jaromanda X I'm not sure what a browser developer console is. I've been trying to debug using W3Schools online TryIt Module. :"fileURL" is a full URL i.e. (https://davidmccabecs.com/wp-content/apps/stocks/current.txt)

Comment: you browser should have developer tools including a console - extremely useful for developers ... F12 on most browsers

Comment: I used a WordPress template to set up my webpages, so I cant find a direct link to the .js file using the developer console.